# Другой компьютер не может подключится к моему серверу import socket python

Tags: python, сокет

Я решил сделать программу, для того чтоб я мог управлять моим компьютером с другого. Но почему-то когда я сам подключаюсь к своему серверу всё работает, а когда я подключаюсь с другого ничего не работает.

Код сервера:

```
import socket
import os

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print("~||-Cервер-активирован-||~\n")
print('Подключено к ', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    udata = data.decode("utf-8")
    if not data:
        break

    os.system(udata)
    print(udata)

conn.close()
print("|-Утеряна-связь-с-клиентом-|\n")
```

Вот мой клиент:

```
import socket

print('Привет! Для того чтоб удостоверится что Вам можно пользоваться компом сервера введите пароль.')

while True:
    passw = str(input("Пароль: "))
    if passw == 'xxxx':
        print('Доступ разрешён')
        break
    else:
        print('Доступ запрещён. Попробуй ещё раз')


sock =  socket.socket ()
sock.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9090))
print("Производим подключение к серверу удалённого доступа к компухтеру...")
while True:
    msg = str(input("Сервер дал ответ на ваш запрос. Введите новый или напишите stop, чтобы прервать связь с сервером: "))
    if msg == "stop":
        print("Прерываем связь с сервером...")
        sock.close()
        print("Вы разорвали соединение")
        break


    sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    print("Вы отправили сообщение. Ждём ответа сервера...")
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно брандмауэр блокирует порт.

Comment: Брандмауэр я отключал и всё равно ничего не работает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял в чём была ошибка. Она очень смешная: я вводил не тот ip-адрес, потому что смотрел его через браузер. Как только я ввёл ip из команды ipconfig всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

sock.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9090))

здесь у тебя должен быть ip сервера или DNS адрес. Так ты пытаешься подключиться к самому себе (127.0.0.1 или localhost) из-за чего у тебя не получаеться подключиться у другому устройству.

```
import socket
import sys 

if len(sys.argv) < 2: # Если пользователь не ввел ip
    print("Usage: {0} <host_ip>".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit() 

print('Привет! Для того чтоб удостоверится что Вам можно пользоваться компом сервера введите пароль.')

while True:
    passw = str(input("Пароль: "))
    if passw == 'xxxx':
        print('Доступ разрешён')
        break
    else:
        print('Доступ запрещён. Попробуй ещё раз')


sock =  socket.socket ()
sock.connect((sys.argv[1], 9090)) # Это должен быть ip компьютера
print("Производим подключение к серверу удалённого доступа к компухтеру...")
while True:
    msg = str(input("Сервер дал ответ на ваш запрос. Введите новый или напишите stop, чтобы прервать связь с сервером: "))
    if msg == "stop":
        print("Прерываем связь с сервером...")
        sock.close()
        print("Вы разорвали соединение")
        break


    sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    print("Вы отправили сообщение. Ждём ответа сервера...")
```

Для исполнения пишешь в консоль:

```
python3 "script_name" "host_ip"
```

Например:

```
python3 client.py 192.168.0.101
```

Что бы узнать ip:
Linux:

```
ip a # or sudo ifconfig
```

Windows:

```
ipconfig
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо за ответ, но у меня возникает такая ошибка при запуске: 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serversock.py", line 51, in <module>
    sock.connect((socket.gethostname(sys.argv[1]), 9090)) # Это должен быть ip компьютера
TypeError: gethostname() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Да, извини, ошибся. Поменяй

sock.connect((socket.gethostname(sys.argv[1]), 9090))

На

sock.connect((sys.argv[1], 9090))

Comment: Тут у меня появилась другая ошибка. :(

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "connect_test.py", line 19, in <module>

    sock.connect((sys.argv[1], 9090)) 

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Comment: Покажи, как ты запускал скрипт, вводил ли ты ip адресс и правилен ли он? Запустил на своей машине, у меня всё получилось. Проверь подключены ли устройства к одной сети? Более подробно прочитай про локальные сети. Удачи!